# Is it possible to use a parameter for LIKE / NOT LIKE

Tags: t-sql, select, stored-procedures, sql-like

I am attempting to pass parameters for LIKE / NOT LIKE and the % signs to make a dynamic query that runs based on what is passed from the application.  I get an error though as TSQL is confused about the parameter for like/not like as its not Boolean.  Is it possible to do it this way or am I going to have to write multiple if statements to check to see what parameters are being passed.

```
@fullName varchar(100), @SrchCriteria1 varchar(15), @SrchCriteria2 varchar(15), 
@fullName1 varchar(100), @SrchCriteria3 varchar(15), @SrchCriteria4 varchar(15),
@fullName2 varchar(100), @SrchCriteria5 varchar(15), @SrchCriteria6 varchar(15),
@qualifer varchar(10), @qualifer1 varchar(10), @qualifer2 varchar(10)

SELECT d.*
FROM   defendants_ALL d, #tmpFullname t1, #tmpFullname1 t2, #tmpFullname2 t3
WHERE  d.combined_name + @qualifer + @SrchCriteria1 + t1.Item + @SrchCriteria2
and  d.combined_name + @qualifer + @SrchCriteria3 + t2.Item + @SrchCriteria4
and  d.combined_name + @qualifer + @SrchCriteria5 + t3.Item + @SrchCriteria6

EXEC uspJudgments @qualifier = 'LIKE', @qualifier1 = 'LIKE', @qualifier = 'NOT LIKE', @fullName = 'johns', @fullName1 = 'jim,j.', @SrchCriteria1 = '%', @SrchCriteria2 = '%',  @SrchCriteria3 = '%', @SrchCriteria4 = '%', @fullName2 = 'johnson', @SrchCriteria5 = '%', @SrchCriteria6 = '%'
```

So that should return all combinations of jim johns and j. johns but will not include jim johnson and j. johnson.  I know that is a rare combination but I couldn't think of a better one ATM that is more common.

Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Query NVarChar(1024)
SET @Query = 'SELECT d.* FROM defendants_ALL d, #tmpFullname t1, #tmpFullname1 t2, #tmpFullname2 t3'  +
'WHERE d.combined_name' + @qualifier + @SrchCriteria1 + 't1.Item' + @SrchCriteria2 +
' and d.combined_name' + @qualifier + @SrchCriteria3 + 't2.Item' + @SrchCriteria4 +
' and d.combined_name' + @qualifier + @SrchCriteria5 + 't3.Item' + @SrchCriteria6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` accepts an expression for the pattern, e.g. `d.combined_name LIKE @SrchCriteria`.

You are attempting to assemble a dynamic query.  To do so, you need to create the entire query in a string and then use `EXECUTE`:

```
declare @Query as NVarChar(1024) = 'SELECT d.* FROM ...' +
  'WHERE d.combined_name ' + @qualifer + @SrchCriteria1 + t1.Item + @SrchCriteria2 +
  '...'
```

The statement may be assembled in several steps before being passed to `EXECUTE`.

Comment: How would I execute that?  Since I am already using Execute for the stored procedure where do I make the execute call and do I need to pass the parameters there?

Comment: @korrowan - I just corrected the answer to show it assembling a query form various constant and variable segments.  Parameters can be passed to the `EXECUTE` statement or combined into the statement as it is being built.  A benefit to assembling the statement this way is that you can add a clause, or fraction thereof, at a time.  For example, based on a parameter or two passed in you could add an `ORDER BY` clause with the appropriate field and direction.  A stored procedure can use `EXECUTE` and may in turn be run using `EXECUTE`.  That isn't a problem.

Comment: I am running into an issue with this and not sure why.  I put the code code above.  If I leave the quotes off of the fields from the temp tables I get an error as SQL does not know where they are so I added quotes but then I get an error when running the above code 'incorrect syntax near d'.  Did I build that incorrectly?

Comment: @korrowan - The common mistakes are leaving out white space when assembling the query (`'SELECT *' + 'FROM'` needs a space before FROM) and not having quotation marks around string values (`+ Alias.ColumnName + @ComparisonOperator + '''' + @ComparisonStringValue + ''''` has explicit quotation marks around the string value).  If you run the query building code in SSMS and examine the assembled string you should be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Habo It appears it works just like it does in Access then and I didn't realize that.  One more question though. In the From clause how do you go about using multiple tables.  It always errors on the temp tables in the FROM clause and I am not sure why.  Do you have to build the From clause in a different manner than I did above?

Comment: @korrowan - I'm a fan of explicitly specifying joins and their conditions: `FROM defendants_ALL as d inner join #tmpfullname as t1 on t1.somecolumn = d.somecolumn inner join ...`.  If you build only the joins that you need then you should be okay.  As it stands, you are inner joining tables that you may or may not try matching based on you search criteria parameters.  If they aren't used in the `WHERE` clause they will cause trouble.

Comment: they are all being used.  There is an if statement that decides which query to use based on if there are any records in the temptable.  In this case I am testing it so ALL 3 tables have a record.

Comment: @korrowan - What error are you getting re: the temporary tables?  I'm wondering if they were created in a scope that isn't accessible to the statement being run by `EXECUTE`.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '#tmpFullname'.

Comment: @korrowan - It's probably right.  A little hard to confirm without seeing the statement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18433/discussion-between-korrowan-and-habo)